# Can li class be swapped with css only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Been made aware you cant swap classes unless its a sibling. so instead of putting the class in a new div im trying to put it into the same list but give it a class to hide, then be visible when another li is hovered.

http://jsfiddle.net/e79g4p1p/13/

```
<div class="bodyfooter_block bbshadowb">
    <p class="typotitle_sml"><?php echo $var_furtherinfotitle; ?></p>
    <p class="typosubtitle_sml"><?php echo $var_furtherinfoheading; ?></p>
    <p class="typotext" style="padding-top:16px;"> 
    <ul class="blocklist">
        <li><a href="" class="hover_text1">text hidden</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="">yugiugugu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ugiugguiug</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ygguiguig</a></li>
        <li><a href="">uihoihoihoih</a></li>
        <li><a href="">uhgiuhiuhuh</a></li>
        <p>po</p>
        <li class="bodyfooter_text1" id="bodyfooter_text1">hidden</li>
    </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

css

```
.hover_text1 {
}

.bodyfooter_text1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.hover_text1:hover > #bodyfooter_text1 {
    list-style-type: none;
    width:260px; 
    height:102px; 
    background: #222222;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    padding:12px; 
    padding-top:6px; 
    border-radius: 6px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Tried with js but doesnt work:

```
$("#hover_text1").hover(function() {
    $(".bodyfooter_text1").addClass("bodyfooter_text1_hover");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e79g4p1p/23/

Comment: I suggest you clean up your code a bit. Use 4 spaces of indentation for code, separated by a newline from other contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ***strongly*** suggest you go over the [basics of CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started) once again.

The problem you face can be overcome using pure CSS - we need a selector called the [General Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

**CSS**

```
.hover_text1:hover ~ #bodyfooter_text1 {
    display: block;
}
```

This, however, requires you to restructure your markup by a marginal amount, so the *"preceded by element"* rule works correctly - the selector we use requires both the preceding and the targeted element to share the same parent:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="blocklist">
    <li class="hover_text1"><a href="">text hidden</a></li>
    <li><a href="">text</a></li>
    <!-- ... -->

    <li class="bodyfooter_text1" id="bodyfooter_text1">hidden</li>
</ul>
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e79g4p1p/26/)

The fiddle I've linked is a *very* simplified version of your code, modified only to highlight the selectors working and nothing else.

Comment: Note that general sibling combinator in conjunction with `:hover` may be buggy in Chrome in some cases (or at least was some time ago).

Comment: works a charm, no need for js which is great which i managed to get going with toggleClass rather then addClass